# Apache Flink - org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient error

Tags: python, java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

```
2024-03-06 16:07:30,202 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [AdminClient clientId=flink-group-enumerator-admin-client] Node 1 disconnected.
2024-03-06 16:07:30,202 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [AdminClient clientId=flink-group-enumerator-admin-client] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: KafkaStream -> Sink: Print to Std. Out' (operator cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:624) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:248) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:395) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:408) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

im trying to start a simple DataStreamJob java application throw Flink Dashboard by upload the .jar file as job and see the results passing throw Flink by Kafka

```
public class DataStreamJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        String topic = "datastreaming";

        try {

            KafkaSource<ProductDto> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<ProductDto>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                    .setTopics(topic)
                    .setGroupId("flink-group")
                    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JSONDeserialization())
                    .build();

            System.out.println("KafkaSource is" );

            DataStream<ProductDto> stream = env.fromSource(kafkaSource , WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),"KafkaStream");

            stream.print();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("System Error" + e.getMessage());

        }

        env.execute("Flink Java API Skeleton");

    }
}
```

All my containers running throw Docker Desktop network with configuration as :-

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.6.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: broker  # Use the container name here
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.1
    container_name: es-container
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    container_name: kb-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.11.1
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-container:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

  jobmanager:
    image: apache/flink:1.18.1
    expose:
      - "6123"  # JobManager RPC port
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"  # Web UI port
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_PORT=6123
      - KAFKA_BROKER=172.21.0.6:9092

  taskmanager:
    image: apache/flink:1.18.1
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    expose:
      - "6121"  # TaskManager RPC port
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - TASK_MANAGER_RPC_PORT=6121
      - KAFKA_BROKER=172.21.0.6:9092

networks:
  flink-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and my data producer code is:-

```
def main():
    topic = 'datastreaming'
    producer = SerializingProducer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
    currTime = datetime.now()
    print(currTime)

    while (datetime.now() - currTime).seconds < 120:
        try:
            transaction = generate_Data()
            transaction['totalamount'] = transaction['product_price'] * transaction['product_quantity']
            print(transaction)
            producer.produce(topic,
                             key= transaction['transaction_id'],
                             value=json.dumps(transaction),
                             on_delivery=deliveryReport
                             )
            producer.poll(0)
            time.sleep(5)
        except BufferError as bufferError:
            print(bufferError)
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note:- when i run the application (.jar) from my IDE everything goes right , but when i submit it as job in Flink dashboard the error above happen.

the connection (Inbound/Outbound is allowed from firewall)

finally my network json is :-

```
[
    {
        "Name": "desktop_default",
        "Id": "8831f8b81f25d4d13d67676c1f7e20a54fec4ea86b4348da4b19e80882e16158",
        "Created": "2024-03-06T15:38:32.165020273Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "682c092703f04eae34cfca7d35b56ecf6d3d0240eec43e1f383a91c177a57533": {
                "Name": "desktop-jobmanager-1",
                "EndpointID": "7d1d606ba193d85550aabf9fb65c9b01225bb167362040192736163693da2140",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "698a123c1cdf1631cb71f8d46d2e074be958b6d2d7de23d571b3200f3a647867": {
                "Name": "postgres",
                "EndpointID": "89c8c7e0d6f3a4b8968e849e474e96fdc7d7cd6bd56d128e963b9a88498fa977",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7287598c074111d11bed32130e9fb86b099861fa2a11b7740678962bbab936d5": {
                "Name": "zookeeper",
                "EndpointID": "911c65b6f047c0ce7e9f8aeca936a24f0d3fbd16695e75d10b8f9db56aea641b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c0651c6f8ea2d62a3486667c8ba5c8b83e8514dd76e8f1c0076a4b666fcbee82": {
                "Name": "es-container",
                "EndpointID": "4f693c0927df1d58e261b793e695f370fb6f522af2bcae9c4c25db299651f7d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d1bc35be349f406aa3c5176a70e4fe674e08a58b08280bfc30dae251533bf111": {
                "Name": "desktop-taskmanager-1",
                "EndpointID": "e4740503a297768a48a2dccd12ab18da885060e294c91b35db35385150db194b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d4ff04fd6c79ba8241765d1955a65c93586609695ffb01476185a42922a850a4": {
                "Name": "kb-container",
                "EndpointID": "b57a8fa414b9e728023d4f0b212cee851cdc04cdd52148acc17a73a24586549c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e8dbc4d6d08faffcb9dbc252b9c7399f4e63e02bb25062e713fd83d882ee6158": {
                "Name": "broker",
                "EndpointID": "1a4d8ed8d1dfecd9f60015e41ece512da533a013fd21dd52a0e54f6df6d4dc42",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "desktop",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.23.3"
        }
    }
]
```